# GLMM: Define zero inflation varying across sites

Tags: mixed-model, modeling, glmm, zero-inflation, glmmtmb

I am fitting a glmm for count data as follow:

```
glmmTMB(counts ~ treatmens + vegetation + days + (1 + treatments|sites), data = data, family = nbinom1, ziformula = ~1))
```

As far as I understand the glmmTMB manual this means that I think that the effect of treatments varies across sites, and that the zero-inflation is assumed to be constant across data.
However, I would like to model it in a way that the zero-inflation will vary by sites.
Now I am a bit confused on how to specify this in the model, something like:

`ziformula = ~sites` or `ziformula = ~(1|sites)`.

It is a bit hard for me to grasp the differences

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer here is not different from any other "should it be fixed or random" decision: are you explicitly interested in which sites have a significantly higher probability of absence, or do you simply want to account for the fact that the probability of absence may vary among them?

See also:

[What is the difference between fixed effect, random effect and mixed effect models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/what-is-the-difference-between-fixed-effect-random-effect-and-mixed-effect-mode)

https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#should-i-treat-factor-xxx-as-fixed-or-random